# Extract specific data from an textfile - csv - Content change every day - "headline" not

Tags: excel, csv, extract

We get every day an csv with data.
The csv is divided in different sections.
Every section has data - headlines and comma separated data.

I only need one section in this csv - the name is every day the same, the headlines also.
The data is different - some day 20 lines - another day 50.

So I have the csv

```
Headline 1
Data...

Headline 2
Data...

...
```

until:

```
Current Sessions
host_delay,User Access Type,launch_duration,session_reconnect,.....
Data
```

I only need what is between Current Sessions and the the next headline, which is:

```
Users Geo Tabular
Data
```

How to resolve this ?
I am not the "scripter"..

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

UNIX (or Linux, if you wish), is excellent for these types of things:

On which line is "Current Session"?

```
UNIX Prompt>grep -n "Current Session" test.csv
8:Current Sessions
```

Only the number, please:

```
UNIX Prompt>grep -n "Current Session" test.csv | awk -F ":" '{print $1}'
8
```

On which line is "Users Geo Tabular"? (Only the number, please)

```
UNIX Prompt>grep -n "Users Geo Tabular" test.csv | awk -F ":" '{print $1}'
12
```

Show me the part of the file between those values:

```
UNIX Prompt>head -n 12 test.csv | tail -n $((12 - 8 + 1))
Current Sessions
...
Users Geo Tabular
```

The used commands (`grep`, `awk`, `head`, `tail`, `$((<integer calculation>))`) are UNIX/Linux commands and features.
How to get UNIX (or Linux) on your PC? There are different possibilities: Cygwin (the mostly used UNIX/Linux commands are converted into Windows commandline programs), WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux, you pretend your Windows computer to be a Linux one), ...